# SQL Server writing conditional join based on values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Transaction` and `Project` that look like this:

```
create table transactions_test
(
    Project nvarchar(50),
    Trans_date  date,
    Amt decimal(24,7)
)

insert into transactions_test (Project, trans_date, amt)
values ('P1', '2019-01-01', 10),
       ('P1', '2019-02-01', 20),
       ('P1', '2019-03-01', 30),
       ('P1', '2019-04-01', 40),
       ('P1', '2019-05-01', 10),
       ('P1', '2019-06-01', 20),
       ('P1', '2019-07-01', 30),
       ('P1', '2019-08-01', 40),
       ('P1', '2019-09-01', 50),
       ('P1', '2019-10-01', 60),
       ('P1', '2019-11-01', 70),
       ('P1', '2019-12-01', 80),
       ('P1', '2020-01-01', 90),
       ('P1', '2020-02-01', 100),
       ('P1', '2020-03-01', 150),
       ('P2', '2019-01-01', 10),
       ('P2', '2019-02-01', 20),
       ('P2', '2019-03-01', 30),
       ('P2', '2019-04-01', 40),
       ('P2', '2019-05-01', 10),
       ('P2', '2019-06-01', 20),
       ('P2', '2019-07-01', 30),
       ('P2', '2019-08-01', 40),
       ('P2', '2019-09-01', 50),
       ('P2', '2019-10-01', 60),
       ('P2', '2019-11-01', 70),
       ('P2', '2019-12-01', 80),
       ('P2', '2020-01-01', 90),
       ('P2', '2020-02-01', 100),
       ('P2', '2020-03-01', 150)

CREATE TABLE [PROJECT_TEST]
(
    [proj_id] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [PLR_Phase] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Effective_Date] [date] NULL,
    [End_Date] [date] NULL
)

INSERT INTO PROJECT_TEST
VALUES ('P1', 'PH1', CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE), CAST('2019-06-01' AS DATE)),
       ('P1', 'PH2', CAST('2019--07-01' AS DATE), CAST('2019-09-01' AS DATE)),
       ('P1', 'PH3', CAST('2019-10-01' AS DATE), NULL),
       ('P2', 'PH1', CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE), NULL)
```

What I need to do is to insert combined values from these tables into a third table

```
CREATE TABLE [RPT_TEST]
(
    [PROJECT] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TRANS_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [AMOUNT] [decimal](24, 7) NULL,
    [PLR_PHASE] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)
```

Here is the issue. In the project_test table projects have effective start and end dates and PLR_Phase attribute changes based on those. If the end date is null the phase applies from start date forward. So  in my reporting table for project P1 I need to have PH1 in PLR_Phase for transactions from January thru June of 2019, PH2 for transactions July thru September of 2019 and PH3 from October of 2019 forward.  For P2 it needs to be PH1 throughout.  How would I accomplish that in a join?

The results I expect to see in the reporting table are below.

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lrsk.png)

Comment: *PH3 from October of 2019 forward* - til when? Today? Heat death of the universe?

Comment: It's ok to use any of the where clause conditions you're used to in a join clause.

Comment: @Caius Jard PH3 until the end date is no longer null, in future reloads. If the end date is null apply to all records in the join if the end date is not null apply to records in that date range.

Comment: @DaleK re *"SO is not a code writing service"* - think somneone needs to tell that to most of the denizens of the [sql] tag then! 

Comment: @CaiusJard - yes - I wonder how many companies have SQL they can't maintain because it was written by Gordon lol

Comment: 62,797 at the moment. More like 62,850 by this time tomorrow.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join predicates don't have to be equality, they simply need to evaluate to a truth. As such you can write something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  transactions_test t
  INNER JOIN 
  project_test p
  ON 
    t.project = p.proj_id AND
    t.trans_date BETWEEN p.effective_date and p.end_date
```

Then all that remains is to deal with the nulls, which is probably easiest to do by giving them a ridiculously future value:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  transactions_test t
  INNER JOIN 
  project_test p
  ON 
    t.project = p.proj_id AND
    t.trans_date BETWEEN p.effective_date and COALESCE(p.end_date, '9999-12-30')
```

This should give you all the columns you desire; you can work on paring then down to just those you want to insert and inserting them to your RPT table

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need just the simple:

```
insert into RPT_TEST
select .....(4 columns you want from joined tables) ...
```

Comment: That won't work since I need a logical if then join almost based on the effective dates of the project in the project table it needs to populate phases in reporting tables for the transactions that match those effective date ranges.